# cannot find symbol Error in Netbeans 8.2

Tags: netbeans

[Error in Netbeans 8.2, cannot find symbol, but compiles just fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW3SH.png)

I'm getting this error when I try to access the Class Settings in the same package. Seems to me the code is fine, because it compiles without errors, also the methods i call from the instance of the Class are all working.

It would be very cool if someone has a solution to this, as it would also bring the auto-completion to work.

Thanks

Comment: The above link shows a screenshot of the IDE, including parts of the code.

Comment: Have you tried using the full package name `xiu.jumpy.Settings` just as a checking measure? Also, have you renamed the class something to Settings.java?

Comment: @Xiutux just close all and reopen the files. Or when you restart Netbeans all errors will be cleared.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a well known issue with NetBeans, with no single solution. You may also find that the problem is intermittent. Search SO using the terms [ netbeans "cannot find symbol" ] to see if any of the many proposed answers help.